# How to profile the CUDA application for a short amount of time by nvprof?

Tags: cuda, nvprof

I wanna to generate a limit profile by nvprof. how to restrict profiling time to just 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvprof has a `timeout` option. From the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#timeout) :

> A timeout (in seconds) can be provided to nvprof. The CUDA application
>   being profiled will be killed by nvprof after the timeout. Profiling
>   result collected before the timeout will be shown.
>
> Note: Timeout starts counting from the moment the CUDA driver is
>   initialized. If the application doesn't call any CUDA APIs, timeout
>   won't be triggered.

Answer (score -1):

You can also mark the beginning and end points in time in which nvprof should apply to. This can be done explicitly using `cudaProfilerStart()` and `cudaProfilerEnd()`, or in an implicit, RAII way using the lifetime a `cuda::profiling::scope` object (from my [Modern C++ CUDA API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/)).

Just remember, if you use nvvp, not to check the box telling it to profile the entire run.